# How change the ip who IdMappedPortTCP1 sends to MappedPort

Tags: delphi

How do to IdMappedPortTCP1 send the client IP instead local ip to destination app?
example at IdMappedPortTCP1.MappedHost i use 127.0.0.1 so the destination app receive the connection ip from localhost (127.0.0.1) and it should be the client ip.

some tunnels do it very well, but using IdMappedPortTCP1 it happens.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not possible with `TIdMappedPortTCP`. The client is not the one connecting to the target app, so the app can't get the client's IP. It can only get the IP of `TIdMappedPortTCP` since that is who is actually connecting to it. The client makes a TCP connection to `TIdMappedPortTCP`, and then `TIdMappedPortTCP` makes a new TCP connection to the target app, and then it forwards data back and forth between those two connections.

Comment: So how the port forwarding works? because have some proxy app's who show the real ip, and not the local ip.

Comment: The only way that is possible is if the port forwarder is altering the TCP packets at the IP level, substituting the client's IP for its own IP inside the packets before forwarding them as-is to the target, and then altering the response packets going in the other direction. `TIdMappedPortTCP` does not operate that way, as it runs at the user level, not the networking level. It doesn't have access to the IP packet headers, not without using RAW sockets, which would severely restrict its usability as RAW sockets require admin rights on most systems.